# Setup OpenVPN network with subnet

Tags: openvpn

I want to set up a OpenVPN network where there will be another subnet network.

My top network located in site A should be able to locate a subnet inside the OpenVPN tunnel in different location, as long as it is a OpenVPN client. Those different locations should never be able to communicate with each other.

The diagram is something like this:

[image]

I think all I need to know is what options does the server have to push to the client. I have all my server configuration ready and my clients can connect to the VPN site but I need to know what to push. I have clients type A which should be able to Access everything and clients type B which only communicate inside their own site.

Im talking about:

```
ifconfig-push 10.10.10.113 10.10.10.114
iroute 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
iroute 172.16.0.0 255.255.0.0
push "route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 172.16.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "redirect-gateway"
```

In the CCD portion of my configuration.

Comment: So you just want to restrict the access be pushing routing network/mask? Pushing each subnet for the clients that need that "type B" 172.16.x.0/24 should do that, but if a client manipulates the routing table he should be able to get to 172.16.0.0/16.

Comment: He should not be able to manipulate the routing table because he is not a admin on the machine that he could manipulate the tables on. He needs a password. So how I can get this up?